# ValueError: Invalid format specifier

Tags: python

I have an integer x and a string y.
X should define how much spaces are after y before there's another string "|".
I'm using the formatting method:

```
    `print("{:<x}|".format(str(k))`
```

When I replace x with a number, it works, but I cant seem to input a variable in the formatting. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`x` in format string is reserved for hex format. If you want to use integer `x` in format string as a align length, you can achieve it replacing `x` with `{}` and passing `x` in format call.

Sample code:

```py
print('{:<{}}|'.format(str(k), x))
```

Result (`k=123`, `x=10`):

```
123       |
```